# cloudfront blocks curl request

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with curl... all I want to do is a grab statistics from website. Problem is cloudfront is blocking this curl request and I can't get any website content to get data... anyway my current curl code:

```
$cookies = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'CDL' ); // for cURL

function getCurlData( $url, $data, $post = false, $http_build_query = false )
{
    global $cookies;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url );

    if( $post )
    {
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

        if( $http_build_query )
        {
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );
        }
        else
        {
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
        }
    }

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    curl_close( $ch );

    return $result;
}
```

and here I do a request:

```
$data= getCurlData( 'https://go.goptions.com/loginaffiliate/', 'command=logon&user=xxx&password=xxx', true );
```

response is my website keep refreshing all the time and when I check html I see this:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><script>window.rbzns = {fiftyeightkb: 43200000, days_in_week : 1};</script><script src="//d1a702rd0dylue.cloudfront.net/js/sugarman/v7/flat.js"></script><script>rbzns.challdomain="go.goptions.com"; rbzns.ctrbg="x3g/GqIS0Y9wYF6hDB2l7067JzcnwlLduB9x4jyL4f+kdAOxPRgRNdkm7uAiNOlc60AoVkIP+RqlM5u87rt4h/dwe2pLn7N6xYW0xhPGlGk5P84LS/fa3yX2VbPgMFDUDl5E1ofBO2IFyaZod0";rbzns.rbzreqid="cellexpertx-reblazer02313433393430309351276c9b6ba24778c"; winsocks(true);</script></body></html>
```

it is possible to skip this cloud or something else to get information from that page?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe they don't like you scraping their content...

Comment: Well client asked me to do this but whatever... any solutions?

Comment: don't scrape. use the official methods: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: Hmm... I'm little bit confused. I don't understand how to use their API... can you explain a bit that I can understand... in that site i can't understand